# What permissions does DocumentRoot directory of Apache Server requies, if its outside /var/www

Tags: server, permissions, apache2

I'm using Ubuntu version 18.04.

I installed `apache2` and tried to set `DocumentRoot` of a `VirtualHost` to be `/home/username/Desktop/work/wp` and it gives error `permission forbidden`.

But if I set `DocumentRoot` from `/var/www`, it works fine.

In both these directories, `user` and `group` are same. I don't understand this. Can somebody help me understand these permissions or direct me to related documentation?
Thanks.

[inside /var/www](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNgye.png)

[outside /var/www](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIyJt.png)

Comment: same perms as inside :: read perms for server execution user

Comment: even perms are the same on both folders and their files but one works and other doesn't. i just don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

To change to a directory, you need +x permission on that directory. To read content of a directory, you need +r on the directory.

To change to `/home/username/Desktop/work/wp/`, you have to give the world execute on the whole path, and read on the `wp` directory.

```
chmod o+x /home/username
chmod o+x /home/username/Desktop
chmod o+x /home/username/Desktop/work
chmod o+rx /home/username/Desktop/work/wp
```

will give these permissions to `other`, which is all users not in your group.